# Handling unknown form data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am posting data to a MVC Controller. The form itself is dynamic. Therefore there is no way to discern rather the form is all textboxes, or radios, or selectboxes, etc.

Creating a model for dynamically generated forms posted data is stumping me. So I was curious if there is a MVC type to just grab the entire form data being passed?

Comment: You can always inspect the query string in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `FormCollection`. Here is a example how to use it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
{
     object something = formCollection["somethingKey"];
     ...
}
```